# Do the same scripts only load once?

Tags: javascript

If i have 2 google ads on a page with this script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
      </script>
```

Will it only get loaded once for the 2 ads or once each script?

Comment: that code simply adds an object to a global array that may or may not exist. it doesn't load any scripts/code on its own. (and i don't see any purpose for it, unless you've omitted important pieces)

Answer (score 1):

see it as this

```
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
```

if variable adsbygoogle is already present then it will be taken from window.adsbygoogle
else window.adsbygoogle will be initialized as a new array[]

then a new object {} will be pushed into that array